# Map based cache with expiration and soft values

Tags: scala, collections, functional-programming

I'm looking to cache information in a Map so I don't have to keep, for example, hitting a DB. In Java I'd use Google collection's excellent [MapMaker](https://github.com/google/guava/commits/master/guava/src/com/google/common/collect/MapMaker.java) and set an expiry, to keep the cache as fresh as necessary, and softValues, to keep the memory usage down. Then I'd have a function that computes the value for a key that currently isn't cached.

```
MapMaker().softValues
          .expireAfterWrite(10, TimeUnit.MINUTES)
          .makeComputingMap(Function(...));
```

What's the best way to do this in Scala?

Comment: If this is working well for you in java, why do it differently in Scala? I'm not aware of any scala-specific libraries for that.

Comment: Well I was hoping for a more idiomatic answer. While Google Guava is excellent I'd rather not have to include the dependency when Scala's collection libraries are so well written as they are.

Comment: And just FYI `MapMaker().softValues` is now [deprecated](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/MapMaker.html#softValues()), use `CacheBuilder.softValues()` instead.

Answer (score 6):

As Kim said, why do it differently if `MapMaker` works well for you?

```
import collection.JavaConverters._
val cache = /* your MapMaker code creating a Java map */.asScala
```

And now you access the underlying Java map with the methods from a Scala map.

Comment: Granted, but as I said to Kim, there must be a more Scala-esque way of doing this?

Comment: @Ben, not out of the box that I know of.

Answer (score 1):

I have created a functionally transparent expiration map in Scala. Adding and removing elements gives a new map, which also removes any expired values.

[Expiration Map](http://higher-state.blogspot.co.uk/2013/02/expiration-map.html)

Answer (score 0):

I'm keep using Guava cache solution in Scala as well :)

First of all, as noted in one of the comments, in newer versions of [Guava Cache](https://github.com/google/guava/wiki/CachesExplained), `MapMaker()` is now deprecated and you should use `CacheBuilder` instead.

So now, in Scala it will look like the follow:

```
  lazy val cachedData = CacheBuilder.newBuilder()
    .expireAfterWrite(60, TimeUnit.MINUTES)
    .maximumSize(10)
    .build(
      new CacheLoader[Key, Data] {
        def load(key: Key): Data = {
          veryExpansiveDataCreation(key)
        }
      }
    )
```

To read from it, you can use something like:

```
  def cachedData(ketToData: Key): Data = {
    try {
      return cachedData.get(ketToData)
    } catch {
      case ee: Exception => throw new YourSpecialException(ee.getMessage);
    }
  }
```